# How to create conditional query with IF(expression, value_if_true,value_if_false) in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How to create query like this ?

```
SELECT id,name,if(id > 17,'yes','no')as present FROM `ref`;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this in Laravel. You can choose to go with the Query builder route or The Eloquent route

With Query builder it will go like this

```
DB::table('ref')->select(['id','name',DB::raw('(case when (id > 17) then "yes" else "no" end) as present')])->get();
```

And with Eloquent you can choose to use Accessor and Mutators or add DB::raw in your select query

with Mutators and Accessors, You first append your new header/attribute to your attributes like so

```
protected $appends = ['present'];
```

then you write your condition for your new header/attribute.

```
public function getPresentAttribute(){

   if($this->attributes['id'] > 17)
      return $this->attributes['present'] = "yes";
   return $this->attributes['present'] = "no"; 

}
```

With this anytime you query the **Ref Model** the **present** attribute will be added to your query result with a value of **yes** or **no** depending on your condition.

And you can choose to use the **DB::raw** in your Eloquent also thereby to forgo the accessor/mutator route

```
App\Ref::select(['id','name',DB::raw('(case when (id > 17) then "yes" else "no" end) as present')])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `CASE` statement

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN <test>      THEN <returnvalue>
            WHEN <othertest> THEN <returnthis>
                             ELSE <returndefaultcase>
       END AS <newcolumnname>
FROM <table>
```

In Laravel use a `Raw()` SQL statement there is no equivalent in Eloquent.